# Android: two event listeners - how to call both

Tags: android, events, listener, onclicklistener, arcgis

**Problem:**
I have two listeners, `OnSingleTapListener` and `OnGraphicClick` <-ArcGIS-related listener. My problem is that one of my listeners intercepts user input over the other.

**Goal:**
Take a look at my attached screenshot; I'd like both listeners to be called when a user taps the "tap here" icons. Currently, when a user taps on the "tap here" icon - `OnGraphicClick` seems to intercept the user event and `OnSingleTapListener` is not called.

I tried to think of a way to call the `onSingleTap` method in `OnSingleTapListener` manually, but it requires `float` parameters (the screen position of where the user clicked) and `OnGraphicClick` takes an ArcGIS `graphic` object: the parameters for the two respective methods are not related.

**Questions to Consider**

- Is there a way to mimic a user event by doing something similar to
  the `performClick` method that will perform a single tap
  at the location that the user tapped the "tap here" icon?
- Could I perhaps make an invisible view placed atop the map view and place the `OnSingleTapListener` on that invisible view? If I did that would the user's tap events trickle down passed the invisible view to also interact with `onGraphicClick` listener placed on the map view?

**Useful Info:**
I'm working with the ArcGIS API for Android.

I have two listeners. One `OnSingleTapListener` that is set on a `MapView` object (main view with all the map stuff) and one ArcGIS-related `onGraphicClickListener` that is also set on the `MapView` object.

```
MySingleTapListener mySingleTapListener = new MySingleTapListener(mMapView.getContext(), mMapView);
mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener(mySingleTapListener);
mMapViewHelper = new EnhancedMapViewHelper(mMapView, handler, this); //<--onGraphicClickListener is set here
```

*sample screen display*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get both listeners to work in tandem. However, I did find a solution.

The `MapView` class contains a `toMapPoint` method that converts screen coords to map coords. Here's how you can utilize this method:

1. Simply set an `OnSingleTapListener` on the `MapView` being used.
2. Have the `onSingleTap` method of the `OnSingleTapListener` convert every user event to map coords via the `toMapPoint` method.
3. If the map coords are equivalent to the map coords of the  "tap here" icons, then do something i.e. display a popup at those screen coords.